# How can I stop Firefox from intercepting the '/' key event?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I miss using it to activate the search field in DuckDuckGo. Can anyone please give me advice on how to stop Firefox from intercepting <kbd>/</kbd> from webpages?

Comment: No, this isn't stackoverflow, it's superuser. I'm a user of DDG, and would like to enjoy the use of the '/' keyboard shortcuts, which on other browsers would activate the query field.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is the only mainstream browser I am aware of that has this shortcut.

Regardless, you could try the [Keybinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keybinder/) addon if you have a Firefox version earlier than 57 and see if that could offer similar functionality. Otherwise, I am not sure if this is even possible with an addon. They were [discussing if they would even expose an API for shortcuts in Quantum](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215061#c66) in December 2017.

One other possibility would be [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com) but you would have to likely have to experiment with the desired keystrokes yourself.

Comment: I'm running Fedora LXDE, and the latest Firefox. Would it even be responsible to run an older version of Fx than the latest one? It's sad that they broke so many excellent addons like Lazarus form recovery and others. There were some really top-notch addons that had been under development for over a decade and some of them seem to simply be gone from Firefox, a bit of a tragedy.

Comment: Regarding responsibility, probably not. However, if your not deep into new features, Firefox ESR (Extended Support Release) versions may be something to consider. They are intended for organizations (which move slowly between browser versions) but they can be publicly downloaded from Mozilla very easily. The benefit is, despite their relative age, they get high-risk/high-impact security vulnerability updates regularly for their support cycles. About addons generally, I agree it is sad to see so much hard work and usefulness cast off by the wayside. Tragedy isn't an overstatement in my opinion.